# how can i pull window container on host window in docker ?

Tags: docker

I am trying to pull window container on window host . But it throw

C:\Users>docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016
ltsc2016: Pulling from microsoft/windowsservercore
3889bb8d808b: Pulling fs layer
c0f6863f3dd4: Pulling fs layer
image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform

can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker host is configured to run in Linux containers inside VM. You need to switch to windows containers.

Screen shots and navigation reference here - [link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers)